# Splitting string in array of maximum 200 Characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to split string into array of max 200 characters each.

I have tried two solutions:

```
const sampleString =`The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.`;

sampleString.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").match(/.{1,200}\./g);
//outputs 7 items, if . is not found under 200 chars it will skip those characters. also some items are way too short.

sampleString.replace(/.{200}\S*\s+/g, "$&@").split(/\s+@/);
//outputs 4 items, but some are well over 200 chars
```

Items length should always be below 200 and should split to nearest ending sentence on ",/./?/!/..." as delimiters.

Comment: Maybe you can just match `[\s\S]{1,200}(?=[.,?!]|$)`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1qO6zY/1).

Comment: Avoiding short items will be hard. You need to define your threshold. Try `s.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '').match(/[^!.?]{200}|.{1,200}(?:[!?.]|$)/g)`

Comment: @41686d6564 regex take commas and full stops to the beginning of next item, It's essential that they stay with previous array items

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake. Try `[\s\S]{1,199}[.,?!]|[\s\S]{1,200}$`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/twa1s3/1). Or `\ ?(?:[\s\S]{1,199}[.,?!]|[\s\S]{1,200}$)` if you don't want the leading space to count towards the 200 max. chars.

Comment: Note that if you're going to remove the linebreaks anyway, then `[\s\S]` wouldn't be needed; you can just use `.` instead. I first thought that you were removing linebreaks as a workaround or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the linebreaks (and include them in the count), you may use this pattern<sup>1</sup>:

```
/.{1,199}[.,?!]|{1,200}$/gs
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dd0ZKz/1)**.

Note that this will include the trailing space in the count. If you want to prevent that, use:

```
/\ ?(?:.{1,199}[.,?!]|.{1,200}$)/gs
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XcfCOy/1)**.

If you're going to be removing linebreaks anyway, you can just remove the `s` flag at the end of the pattern:

```
var result = 
    sampleString.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, "").match(/\ ?(?:.{1,199}[.,?!]|.{1,200}$)/g);
```

**Breakdown:**

```regex
\ ?              # Match zero or one space character.
(?:              # Start of a non-capturing group.
    .{1,199}     # Match between one and 199 characters.
    [.,?!]       # Match exactly one character among [.,?!] (total of 200, max.)
|                # OR:
    .{1,200}$    # Match between one and 200 characters at the end of the string.
)                # End of the non-capturing group.
```

---

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>Which is equivalent to the pattern I provided in the comments: `/[\s\S]{1,199}[.,?!]|[\s\S]{1,200}$/g`.</sub>

Comment: there seem to be one problem, if no characters among [.,?!] are matched, it totally leaves out the previous characters

Comment: That's true. What do you want to happen in that case? Go over the 200 chars limit or split exactly at 200 chars if none of `[.,?!]` exists? Or something else?

Comment: It should take those 200 characters and put it in the array and go to next 200 iteration

Comment: Try removing the `$` at the end of the pattern. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/o9CZN1/1).